# After the local installation of an old WP website I can see the homepage but I can't access to the articles, why?

Tags: posts, permalinks, links, content

I have import on my local webserver a backup of a website made using WordPress but I am finding some difficulties with **PermaLink**

The main problem is that if I use the permalink setted as **Article Name** I can see the homepage but if I click on the articles links into the homepage (to see the article) I always obtain the following message error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
>   /wordpress35/2012/10/11/se-milano-avesse-il-mare-anzi-no-la-montagna-di-campiglio/
>   was not found on this server.

If I instead I use the **Default** settings for permalink (`http://localhost/wordpress35/?p=123`) I have no problem and I can access to the articles in my website

Why? What can I do to try to solve this problem? (I need to use the URL format described as: `http://localhost/wordpress35/my-article-name`

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if permalinks worked on your local server before the import or not you ether need to update the .htaccess in your wordpress root, or you need to enable rewrites all together in Apache. What operation system do you use?

This is a good guide if you use linus:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite